# What am I doing wrong with Copy-Item?

Tags: powershell

`Copy-Item` trips me up every time I use it. Would someone please tell me what I did wrong here?

I have a set of folders:

```
C:\FolderA\Thing\Sub1\1_file.css
C:\FolderA\Thing\Sub2\A_file.css
C:\FolderA\Thing\page.html
```

I try to use `Copy-Item` to send them to `C:\FolderB\*` and preserve structure:

```
Copy-Item -Path $srcFolder\Thing\* -Destination $destFolder\Thing -Recurse -Force -Verbose
```

Expected result:

```
C:\FolderB\Thing\Sub1\1_file.css
C:\FolderB\Thing\Sub2\A_file.css
C:\FolderB\Thing\page.html
```

Instead I end up with:

```
C:\FolderB\Sub1\1_file.css
C:\FolderB\Sub2\A_file.css
C:\FolderB\page.html
```

There's clearly a `\Thing` folder in there, so why doesn't it create the `\Thing` if I'm telling it to go recursively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell it to create the directory before the copy, for example:

```
$dst = C:\FolderB\Thing
New-item $dst -type directory
```

`

Comment: this sounds like it works best when I know exactly what I'm copying. Looks like I should switch to robocopy then.